# wrong position when using select2 dropdownAutoWidth

Tags: javascript, jquery-select2

That's the code:

```
this._select = $(select).select2({
    width: '100%',
    dropdownAutoWidth: true,
}).on('select2:select', this._onChange);
```

Turns out that when the dropdown is too close of the right border its gets cutted off as you can see here:

[image]

There is a way/option to solve this? I don't find anything related in the docs.

Looks like it's always positioned at bottom left corner of the select, ignoring the window width.

Thanks!

Comment: Simply lower the width, or use a `margin-right`?

Comment: Well I think this is an issue, more info here: https://github.com/select2/select2/issues/4497